# How do I run a folder of migrations in one migration

Tags: laravel

When I started this project, I renamed specific migration files to start with 9999, so I would assure they ran last when running a fresh migration.

I soon found this was a mistake, because now I have over 200 migration files and every time I create a new migration that inserts default data I have to rename my migration file. Long story short, I should have just left my migration files to run sequentially and not altered them.

What I am trying to do now is move all my existing migrations to a new folder, then run that folder first and all other migrations after that. This way I don't need to change all 200+ database records and file names and all new migrations would just run as they should have.

[image]

Im not sure if this is even possible or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to run that command inside the migration you can do:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan;

Artisan::call('artisan migrate --path=/database/migrations/OldMigrations/*);
```

Answer (score 0):

Run this artisan command It will work:

```
php artisan migrate --path=/database/migrations/OldMigrations/*
```

Comment: Is there any way I can run this command within the migrate-old-data migration

Comment: This command will help You to achieve that.Run only migration files inside OldMigrations folder